# Glue two spheres

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Taking a small open neighbourhood around a point $p$ in $S^3$ gives a new domain $M=S^3\setminus U(p)$, then gluing $M$ with itself along the boundary will give a new space $\tilde{M}\sim S^3$. I am just curious if I do the similar thing to a circle instead of point $p$. what will the new space look like ? Or what topology does this new space has ? for example, how do fundamental groups change $\pi_1,\pi_2$?

Comment: For the former, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum . Since reduced homology (of pointed spaces) is additive under wedge sum, $S^3\vee S^3$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^3$.

Comment: @anomaly, sorry I think I didn't ask the question as I wanted. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking about is called ["Dehn surgery"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_surgery) of 3-manifolds. You can get an incredible number of different 3-manifolds, with very different fundamental groups, by taking a knot in $S^3$, deleting a neighborhood, then gluing it back in by a diffeomorphism of the boundary; the best way to talk about what $\pi_1$ is of the result is to talk about $\pi_1$ the knot complement.

It's a big subject, you might enjoy reading about it.